# Getting strings from a file

Tags: bash, scripts

Trying to write a script for taking strings from a puppet file. There is a such lines in file.pp

```
$get_modules           = ['string_agent1',
                      'string',
                      'string_agent2',
                      'string-agent3']
```

How to get only values without quotes from a file? After that, checking if files existing with names *string_agent1, string, string_agent2, string_agent3*

Tried to do like this

```
tr -d [:space:] < file.pp | sed -n 's:.*get_modules=\[\(.*\)]\#.*:\1:p'
```

But the output is as the following

```
'string_agent1','string','string_agent2','string_agent3'
```

But need to get like the following

```
string_agent1
string
string_agent2
string_agent3
```

Comment: Pipe end result to `tr -s \', '\n'`

Comment: @Raffa it works! Thanks a lot! If you could add your comment as an answer, so I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the output is as the following
>
> ```
> 'string_agent1','string','string_agent2','string_agent3'
> ```
>
> But need to get like the following
>
> ```
> string_agent1
> string
> string_agent2
> string_agent3
> ```

Since you are already familiar with `tr`, you can pipe the end result to `tr` and use it like so:

```
tr -s \', '\n'
```

This will replace every occurrence of `'` and `,` with newline and `-s` will squeeze multiple occurrences of newline in a sequence to just one newline character.